# Call external mail api within lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I use claudiajs apibuilder to develop some REST API. I want to use within this api the pepipost email api to send transactional email. The api work well outside my lambda function during the test. When I include the epi in lambda they stop working and no errors are thrown.

There is some permissions to set? or something others settings required to call an external api?

I've tried to clean up the function to leave only the email sending to better debug it

This is the test endpoing

```
api.post('/users/test', function(request) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let eTo = "email@email.com", 
            eSubject = 'Activate your account',
            eAttributes =  {
                            THE_NAME            :   "userData.name",
                            THE_ACTIVATION_URL  :   "config.activationUrl"+"/123456",
                            THE_ACTIVATION_LINK :   "config.activationLink",
                            THE_ACTIVATION_CODE :   "aToken"
                        },
            eType = 'eTActivationEN',
            eTags = 'activation';

        sendemail( eTo, eSubject, eAttributes, eType, eTags );
        resolve( { "success" : "works" } );


    });

},{ success : { code : 200}, error : { code : 401 } });
```

this is the module that send the email:

```
var http = require("https");
var e = require('./../config.json');


module.exports.send = ( eTo, eSubject, eAttributes, eType, eTags ) => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        var options = {
          "method": "POST",
          "hostname": "api.pepipost.com",
          "port": null,
          "path": "/v2/sendEmail",
          "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "api_key": e.ePepipostToken
          }
        };

        var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
          var chunks = [];

          res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
          });

          res.on("end", function () {
            var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            output = body.toString();
            resolve ( output );
          });
        });

        req.write(JSON.stringify({ 
            personalizations: [ 
                { 
                    recipient: eTo,
                    attributes: eAttributes
                } 
            ],
            from: { fromEmail: e.eFromAddress, fromName: e.eFromName },
            subject: eSubject,
            templateId: 18924,
            tags: eTags,
            content: "content" }));
        req.end();

    }) // end Promise
}
```

The same module works well outside lambda, but not working inside.
When I try to call the endpoint I receive {"success" : "works"} but no email. And no error il cloudwatch console.

Answer (score 0):

update:

If I include all the send email code it works:

```
api.post('/users/test2', function(request) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

var http = require("https");


            var options = {
              "method": "POST",
              "hostname": "api.pepipost.com",
              "port": null,
              "path": "/v2/sendEmail",
              "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "api_key": config.ePepipostToken
              }
            };

            var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
              var chunks = [];

              res.on("data", function (chunk) {
                chunks.push(chunk);
              });

              res.on("end", function () {
                var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                output = body.toString();
                resolve ( output );
              });
            });

            eAttributes =  {
                THE_NAME            :   "userData.name",
                THE_ACTIVATION_URL  :   "config.activationUrl"+"/123456",
                THE_ACTIVATION_LINK :   "config.activationLink",
                THE_ACTIVATION_CODE :   "aToken"
            }

            req.write(JSON.stringify({ 
                personalizations: [ 
                    { 
                        recipient: "email@email.com",
                        attributes: eAttributes
                    } 
                ],
                from: { fromEmail: "devm425tj@pepisandbox.com", fromName: "me" },
                subject: "eSubject",
                templateId: 18924,
                tags: "activation",
                content: "content" }));
            req.end();


    });

},{ success : { code : 200}, error : { code : 401 } });
```

The problem is that I cannot include the same code for every email that I need to send. I need to let it work from external module.

Answer (score 0):

2nd update: the code works well, the problem is in the caludiajs apibuilder, I cant call external function from the api.post("something") block, I'll try to understant how to..